# Removing the default selected row on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have a `Datagridview` that contains columns. 
when i click on the item on the column.  
it always select the first row

i also tried

```
.currentcell = null and .clearselection();
```

// i inserted this one on the `form_load`

but nothing happens.

here is my code

```
private void dgv1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) 
            {
                dgv1.CurrentCell = null;
                dgv1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".pdf")
            {

                Process.Start(path);
            }

            }

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it always selects the first row"? Are you saying that the cell that is clicked is not selected?

Comment: when i click on the cell (not on the first row) it always selects the first row. so when i try to epen something in diffent row. it always displays the details on the first row. (I think it's always selecting the first row by default)

Comment: Could you include the rest of the code from the `dgv1_CellContentClick` method? Are there any other events you are handling or settings we should know about? At this stage I can't reproduce the bahaviour you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the user to select in the first place?
There is a property for selectionmode in datagridview.
Change it to CellSelect if you want it to select cells only. 
Alternatively, use `dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;`

After reading what you said on the comment, from that I infer that you are trying to click a cell and read the cell from your program?

If so, you could try

```
dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

on the CellContentClick and/or CellClick event

Comment: i tried this one. when i use the breakpoint it shows me what cell i selected. but after that. my code still applies it on the first row. i also add .currentcell before the code you have given me a while ago.

Comment: try using the CellClick event handler instead of the CellContentClick event handler and see if that changes anything. I can't seem to replicate the problems that you are having?
Do you mind posting everything else that is related to dgv1? And did you set the variable "path" to something?